# Can I use $emit in a prototype

Tags: angularjs, prototype, emit

`Edit : corrected the foo method.`

I'm a junior in angularJS, and am struggling with this.
I'm using a directive with prototype methods, and I would like to emit an even inside one of them, but I've not been able to make it work so far.

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
            },
            bindToController: true,
            controller: MyController,
            controllerAs: 'myCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'template/myTemplate.html'
        };
    }
);
```

Then I have the controller that looks like this.

```
var MyController= (function () {
    function MyController($mdComponentRegistry, $attrs, $log,$scope) {
        this.$scope = $scope;
        this.$mdComponentRegistry = $mdComponentRegistry;
        this.$attrs = $attrs;
        this.$log = $log;
        this.steps = [];
        this.currentStep;
    }
MyController.prototype.foo = function () {
        this.$scope.$emit('fooEvent');
    });
```

It looks like I messed up with the $scope injection, as it's not defined.

Could anyone tell me what I did wrong ? That would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: The controller code doesn't make sense. What is `StepperCtrl` and how is it related to the controller code?

Comment: I recommend isolate scope directives avoid using $emit to communicate events. Instead communicate events with expression `&` binding.

Comment: You are showing `MyController` as the constructor and then a prototype method of `StepperCtrl` - is this a typo? If it is and you meant to use `MyController.prototype.foo` then you can just do `this.$scope.$emit` in the prototype method because you already set `this.$scope` in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You defined `this.$scope = $scope;` in constructor, so you should also access scope as instance property:

```
this.$scope.$emit('fooEvent');
```

Comment: Tried that, but I had the error $emit is undefined or something.

Comment: @BigFoot - `is undefined or something` - that's an extremely unhelpful error message to tell somebody who is trying to help you.

Comment: @Adam - My apologies, I was just about to leave the office and couldn't recall the exact error, and had no time to reproduce it then. Here it is :
`TypeError: Cannot read property '$emit' of undefined`

Comment: @BigFoot You need to show the usage of this controller and also post its complete code not clipped randomly as it's now. You are returning constructor from IIFE, for example?

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, here is an example of how to write a controller as a class:

```js
class MyController {
    constructor($mdComponentRegistry, $attrs, $log,$scope) {
        this.$scope = $scope;
        this.$mdComponentRegistry = $mdComponentRegistry;
        this.$attrs = $attrs;
        this.$log = $log;
    }
    $onInit() {
        this.hello = 'hello';
        this.currentStep;
        this.foo();
    }
    foo() {
        console.log("Executing foo function");
        console.log(this.$scope.myCtrl.hello);
        console.log("$emit is a", typeof this.$scope.$emit);
    }
}
MyController.$inject = ['$mdComponentRegistry', '$attrs', '$log', '$scope'];

angular.module('myModule',[])
    .directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            scope: {
            },
            bindToController: true,
            controller: MyController,
            controllerAs: 'myCtrl',
            template: 
               `<fieldset>myDirective {{myCtrl.hello}}
                </fieldset>` 
        };
    }
)
.value('$mdComponentRegistry', {})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="myModule">
    <h2>Controller Written as a Class</h2>
    <my-directive></my-directive>
  </body>
```